# Why eOS is still based on Ubuntu and not on Linux Mint?

Tags: kernel, ubuntu, elementary-project

I've been wondering this for a while, those last Ubuntu LTS are really buggy, last night I tried to use the last LTS and it didn't last 10min without breaking alone, just by updating the system. I am asking this as a total noob in this field.

Linux Mint looks like the most stable distro we have right now(ubuntu based), that said, why eOS is still based on Ubuntu? Is it hard/impossible to be based on some distro like Linux Mint?

I saw a lot of users complaining about eOS bugs and unstability. I had some myself, but as I am a developer I am always breaking something, rs. But it isn't those bugs Ubuntu's fault?

Comment: Linux Mint is also based on Ubuntu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint

Comment: I know that, but right now Mint is way more stable than Ubuntu it self, thats my point.